# Xamarin.Android textview event handler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxAutoCompleteTextView which has a event handler (KeyPress)
But the event only gets called when I press the enter key!

I also have a almost Identical MvxAutoCompleteTextView and its event handler does work like it should. Has someone run into this before?

```
    {    
        klantNummerTextView.KeyPress += KeyPress;
        klantNaamTextView.KeyPress += KeyPress;
    }

    private void KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {}
```

This is their xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
    <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Klant nummer"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal"
      android:id="@+id/nummertextbox"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/klanthintitemtemplate"
      local:MvxBind="Text KlantResponse.Nummer; ItemsSource KlantNamen; 
     PartialText CurrentKlantHint; SelectedObject SelectedKlant" />
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
    <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Klant naam"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:id="@+id/naamtextbox"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/klanthintitemtemplate"
      local:MvxBind="Text KlantResponse.Naam; ItemsSource KlantNamen; 
      PartialText CurrentKlantHint; SelectedObject SelectedKlant" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Please update your post with a code comparative between both MvxAutoCompleteTextViews. It would help us to give you a path to fix it.

Comment: @DanielCorzo I have added the other one now! Thanks for your reply